# Where can I find a Brother HL2140 64-bit driver?

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I was running a Brother HL2140 happily on my Win7 desktop, but with support running out, I opted to install Ubuntu 19.04 rather than go to Win10.

I've been learning a little by installing and running earlier versions of Ubuntu for a few years on the kids' PC, but I'm no programmer, so when something complex comes up, I'm floored.

Ubuntu / Settings / Printers sees the HL2140, searches for drivers, and installs a generic-text-only-printer 'CUPS-BRF printer'.

If I print a test from LibreOffice Writer, the printer churns out heaps of blank pages. I tried Printer / Details / Search for drivers, and tried all the available drivers, but without success.

Suggestions?

Comment: I just needed to wait. Ubuntu 20 comes with support for the Brother HL2140.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to wait. Ubuntu 20 came with built in support for Brother HL2140. Thanks to those who responded.

Answer (score 0):

Good timing, I got my Brother 2142 running this week. The main issue was printing blank pages without end (an old issue)..

This is how I did it.

download the deb driver (i386 still works for me with this). rpm is also available there (bottom of the page)

http://www.printercentrals.com/2015/03/brother-hl-2142-driver-windows-mac.html

```
sudo deb brhl2140lpr-2.0.2-1a.i386.deb
```

it picked my printer up as a 2140, and works ok
if you get a "specify the device URI" pick "no"

to cancel print jobs, or stop it printing off endless blank sheets - replace your

```
cancel -u <username>
```

and alternative is the installer tool
https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/52188/~/install-drivers-%28deb-or-rpm%29-using-the-driver-install-tool---linux

```
sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1
```

type your model, 2140, when asked.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I downloaded linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1 and did the sudo bash, typing in HL2140 and then choosing no when asked "specify the device URI" but didn't see anything about  cancel u- <username> before it asked me whether to print a test page. I typed 'y' and hit Enter when asked but nothing printed, either then or from LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: hi, sorry , that cancel -u was not part of the solution, that was just what to do if you encountered the endless blank sheet printing problem. maybe try HL-2140   . and maybe try the deb method above .

Comment: Can't seem to find brhl2140lpr-2.0.2-1a.i386.deb either at http://www.printercentrals.com/2015/03/brother-hl-2142-driver-windows-mac.html or using Google.

Comment: at the bottom of that page for Linux there are these links     

 http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf006677/brother-laser2-cups-driver-2.0.2-1.tar.gz    http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf005856/brhl2140lpr-2.0.2-1.i386.rpm    http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf005857/brhl2140lpr-2.0.2-1.i386.deb

Comment: I downloaded from both those links, installed cupswrapperHL2140-2.0.2-1a.i386.deb then brhl2140lpr-2.0.2-1a.i386.deb and my HL2140 now works! Thanks pierrely :)

Comment: good oh, I also was going to suggest a printer-only self test, which youd have to look up in the manual.

Comment: Manual? Real men don't read manuals ;)

Comment: they used to when manuals were large and heavy and frequently lifted. also might be worth noting that you might be able to designate the HL-2142 model the works for HL-2140, something I saw in my notes.

Comment: just adding, I had to reinstall the printer. using the sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1 method I input the model number as HL-2142 , NOT HL-2140 even though that is my model number. otherwise I got the blank pages or not connecting error.

Comment: Hoping you're still watching this pierrely. I had a crash while trying to upgrade to 19.1 and lost my HL2140 printer, so I need to install it again. Reading back over your instructions, I can't recall what I did to get it to work. Would you mind giving step by step instructions for a bear of very little brain? Many thanks.

Comment: hi, I had no issues with my upgrade fortunately. my last success was  trying the deb file, not that choosing 2142 works for my 2140.
http://www.printercentrals.com/2015/03/brother-hl-2142-driver-windows-mac.html
brhl2140lpr-2.0.2-1a.i386.deb  -  ah just checked that page no longer available  .........  this link for exe for windows only https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2140_all&os=135   .......        (any idea on how to do a line break in these comments here?  )
works as a 2140 and on a 64bit system.

Comment: this link worked  for the download    http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf005857/brhl2140lpr-2.0.2-1.i386.deb

Comment: Okay. Went to  download.brother.com/welcome/dlf005857/…, downloaded and installed that but can't remember what the next step is, and can't get it from looking at the earlier comments. Sorry. I'm a bit dim at times, possibly due to having been dead two or three times from bike crashes ;) I see that the last time I installed cupswrapper but I can't see a link to that.

Comment: I am a bit dim sometimes too... in terminal        deb files are                                 
  dpkg -i  <filename>                                                                                            
 and actually I just double clicked it on Opera browsers download window  and it came up to install. (a new 19.10 upgrade seems to have done that trick)

Comment: It was the 19.01 upgrade that caused the crash that lost my driver ;) I think I'm going to backup everything, try the upgrade on my newer PC and see if Ubuntu 19.01 can deal with my HL2140. Not sure when I'll be able to get to that but watch this space for a situation update.

Comment: Got it going by following your instructions re reinstalling and calling it an HL2142. Thanks, Pierrely :)

Comment: good oh.  I have learned to take notes on these things. above error should be "note that choosing 2142 works for me"